# what is the multicast doing on 224.0.0.251?

Tags: dns, debian, mdns

On my debian server (squeeze) I get this message every few seconds:

> Sep 18 21:28:14 myhost kernel: [7903784.720091] AIF:UNPRIV connect
>   attempt: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=**my_serverip_eth0** DST=224.0.0.251
>   LEN=72 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353
>   LEN=52

the packets are coming from inside my server (i replaced it with **my_serverip_eth0**) and seem to be blocked going out to the destination 224.0.0.251.

So some task inside my server is contacting 224.0.0.251 and this is blocked by my `arnos_firewall`.

How can I find out who or which task is trying to do that and if it is useful or not?

And if I don't need it, how can I suppress that message then?

Comment: Hi there. Your question isn't exactly on topic for Stack Overflow as there isn't any programming involved (not that I can see). Would you like me to move your question to another site (say, Server Fault or Unix & Linux)?

Comment: yes, please move it to a fitting stack

Comment: The Apple iTunes and Avahi daemon has been mentioned, but the elephant in the room is chrome browser. For example take a look at here: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/5939360?hl=en

Answer (score 50):

Those look much like [Bonjour / mDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) requests to me. Those packets use multicast IP address 224.0.0.251 and port 5353.

The most likely source for this is [Apple iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1601), which comes pre-installed on Mac computers (and is a popular install on Windows machines as well). Apple iTunes uses it to discover other iTunes-compatible devices in the same WiFi network.

mDNS is also used (primarily by Apple's Mac and iOS devices) to discover mDNS-compatible devices such as printers on the same network.

If this is a Linux box instead, it's probably the [Avahi daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) then. Avahi is [ZeroConf/Bonjour compatible](http://wiki.debian.org/ZeroConf) and installed by default, but if you don't use DNS-SD or mDNS, it can be disabled.

Comment: but i use debian squeeze. how can i find out which process is using it ?

Comment: Are the packets coming from the Debian box or something else?

Comment: i added explanation to the main question

Comment: OK, that's probably the Avahi daemon then. Its ZeroConf/Bonjour compatible: http://wiki.debian.org/ZeroConf . Can you check if Avahi is installed?

Comment: yes, `avahi-daemon` is installed i removed it and it removed also the packet `libnss-mdns`. what was that for?

Comment: Its only needed if you use DNS-SD or mDNS - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software) . Sounds like you don't need it. :) Its usually installed by default, if I remember correctly.

Comment: sorry, the messages are still there, so uninstalling avahi was not the solution

Comment: mDNS DNS-SD Bonjour has some interest for autodiscovery of printers, it is useful by example for hp laser printers. within cups they appear with an url dnssd:// .

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have avahi installed then it's probably cups.

Answer (score 1):

I deactivated my "Arno's Iptables Firewall" for testing, and then the messages are gone

Comment: although it would still be interesting how to stop the source of the messages instead

Comment: I'm pretty sure its Avahi. Are you sure Avahi got uninstalled - its possible it got reinstalled during an update.

Comment: yes, avahi-daemon and libnss-mdns are still removed

Comment: To remove the error message (and firewall!) isn't really a solution to the problem, is it?  The collateral damage is just too high, I find.  You could just whilelist the service, and that's it.